# What is a quickest way to find inverses of functions of two variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

Suppose I have

$X_1 = aY_1+bY_2$

$X_2 = cY_1+dY_2$

How is the quickest (or most efficient way ) to find the inverse functions?

The current way I am doing it is attempting to solve for Y1 in the first equation and plug it into the second equation.

But there is there some kind of a matrix trick or a fast way to solve these kind of problems?

Comment: The quickest way is to set (a,b,c,d) into a matrix and then invert that matrix then change the places of $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $y_1$ and $y_2$, writing the new set of equations

Comment: Could you please demonstrate this. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I wrote it. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$

You should first invert this matrix. Assume the inverse of this matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}r&t\\g&h\end{bmatrix}$$

Then you will write

$$y_1=rx_1+tx_2$$ and $$y_2=gx_1+hx_2$$